# Property 'name' does not exist on type HTMLInputElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const handleOnChange = (e: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    console.log(e.name);
  }

<input name="aa" onChange={handleOnChange} />
```

Why `HTMLInputElement` doesn't have name attribute in react?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct type for the change event object is: `ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`.

Although the `e.name` isn't exists, the correct way to get the element's `name` attribute is `e.target.name` where the `target` object in the event is the input element itself, and you need the `name` attribute from that.

So your `handleOnChange` method would look like:

```
const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
}
```

Or:

```
const handleOnChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name);
}
```

In this case you define the type for the `handleOnChange` variable, and you  assign the arrow function to that, so TypeScript will infer the type for `e` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can always **target** any **event (e)** by **e.target.YourAttribute**

```
const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => { console.log(e.target.name); }
```